# Error with list as argument of function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

When defining a function which has a list as an argument as follows:

```
f[S_] := S[[1]] S[[2]]

In[30]:= f[S]
Out[30]= S[[1]] S[[2]]
```

I get the following error message

```
During evaluation of In[30]
Part::partd: Part specification S[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

I have looked on the many other posts on how to define a function with a list as an argument, but I could not find the solution to my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: After defining `f`, you call it with `f[S]` - `S` here is a symbol, not a list, it has no depth. The definition says to access parts of a list, so no wonder it doesn't return parts of `S` since they do not exist. With `list = {a, b, c}` you can do `f[list]` which works fine. // It's like defining `root[eq_] := FindRoot[eq == 0, {x, 0}]` and complaining it doesn't give a root of some generic name `eq` with `root[eq]` - there's no equation to solve.

Comment: Ok. The point is that I do not want to explicitly define the elements of S setting S = {a,b,c}. Is there a way of specifying that S is a list of a given length without explicitly setting its elements?

Comment: Why? You defined a function with`f[S_] :=...` for arbitrary list `S`. I don't understand what precisely you want to achieve.

Comment: Given the definition of f[S] above, I want to introduce an additional variable, say U. I want to declare U as a list without setting directly its elements, i.e., I want to avoid doing U = {a,b,c}. Finally, I want f[U] to be evaluated without errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax of your definition of `f`. But it is not a robust definition. The lefthand side of the definition says that anything may be passed as argument, but the righthand side explicitly requires the argument be an expression that has a least two elements. When you call the `f` with an argument that violates this requirement, you must expect to get an error message. If you want `f` to be more robust, that is, to defend against bad arguments, you must add some code to your definition to provide the defense.

The are many approaches that might be used to make your function more robust. I will describe one of simplest, using the built-in function [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (shortcut form `/;` ).

```
Clear[f]
f[s_ /; Length[s] > 1] := s[[1]] s[[2]]
```

This adds a constraint on the argument: it must meet the condition the it has a length greater than one -- it must be an expression with a head and (at least) two elements (parts).

With this new definition, `f` will not accept an atomic expression -- one with no parts.

```
{f[s], f[42], f["hello"]}
```

> `{f[s], f[42], f["hello"]}`

But the both the following will work as you expect them to.

```
With[{s = {a, b, c, d}}, f[s]]
```

> `a b`

```
f[g[a, b]]
```

> `a b`